# '\' not work in equation edit in Microsoft Powerpoint

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I am working on Powerpoint 2016 in Mac OS. Now when I edit the equation, if I input words like *\le* and press space key, it won't transform to <= automatically. I must select <= in the ribbon area. Like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khynX.png)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by deleting the PowerPoint preferences (delete the following two folders, where ~ is your Home folder):

- ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.PowerPoint
- ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office

You will know that you deleted the correct settings if, after doing so, you start PowerPoint and it tells you about the latest features and re-activates your license. Do note that deleting the latter will remove your Outlook profile. Some users recommend just backing it up, and then moving it back again afterwards.

Apparently this tend to happen when you uncheck the auto-correct preference "Capitalize first letter of sentences".

I can confirm that the bug is still there in PowerPoint 16.44.20121301 as of Dec 2020.

More info:

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/symbol-replacement-in-powerpoint-2016-mac-equation/6623d873-62eb-403b-a0fc-472fb5fe2de3
- https://superuser.com/questions/1364885/latex-syntax-no-longer-works-in-powerpoint-equation-editor-how-to-fix-it
- http://tonylimaassociates.com/2020/06/powerpoint-for-the-mac-equation-editor-is-broken/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/automatic-replacement-of-symbols-with-equation-in/8158f22c-7d9f-435d-9545-5b799cc892e7

> In Word, go to Tools> AutoCorrect [or Word> Preferences - AutoCorrect] & you'll see a Math AutoCorrect tab. There you can edit the list & change the settings. Any changes you make apply in all Office programs that support the Equation mechanism.

Comment: Nice idea...but that's how you fix the problem in **Word**; in PowerPoint fo the mac, there's an autocorrect-preferences dialog...but no **Math**autocorrect tab. Sigh.